# Block chain beginner questions

Tags: blockchain, mining, nodes, proof-of-stake

I am new to this Block Chain environment and this is not an excuse for asking this basic doubt its just that I am very curious about this question and I am not able to find any answer to this question.
The questions are:

1.) What is the functionality of the node. What I have understood by far is that a node has to find the solution of a question and if some node finds the solution(nonce) to the question that block gets mined. Does this process happen in any form of consensus for example does this also happen in the proof of stake?

2.) Does the node validate the transaction(validate in the sense that it checks if the user is capable of spending the requested amount of token which they have requested) and also solve the tough question provided by the block chain to get the solution(nonce) in order to mine a block in the block chain?

3.) What if I want to make a decentralised twitter, will the users have to pay money to send any message on it? Because according to my learnings so far each block has to mined and it will need some gas to be mined, so why would anyone shift to block chain if that thing is free in centralised network

4.) When I as a user am making any transaction on the block chain,for instance I am sending money to some one else, then I am interacting with the smart contract right? so how would the node know which smart contract should be executed because there might be many contracts on that node isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!

1. Nodes provide information to clients and they also participate in propagating the blockchain information to other nodes. [Here](https://consensys.net/knowledge-base/how-does-a-blockchain-work/) is a good resource that explains this.
2. Miners typically are also full nodes so that they have the necessary information to mine. However not all nodes are miners.
3. There are many ways to design a decentralized twitter, but in the most straightforward case where tweets are stored on the blockchain people will have to pay to tweet in your decentralized twitter. Thy would have to feel that the advantages of the blockchain (non-censorship, immutability, etc) outweigh the cost of the message.
4. An address doesn't have to interact with a smart contract to send eth to another address. However, in the case of when you do send money to a contract, you have to be sure you're sending it to the right contract. Each contract has an address so you send money there. For instance the contract address of the Bored Ape Yacht Club NFT is 0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d. You can find it by looking at opensea, typing in "bored ape" and clicking on a bored ape. The contract address will be in the URL. You can then search for that address on etherscan.io and find all the transactions for the contract.

Good luck with your adventures in Ethereum!